# Create vector of symbolic variables by name through iteration

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

I'm trying to create a growing vector inside a for-loop, i.e. the vector is initialized with one element (lets call it q_1) and in the next iteration of the loop the vector is expanded by a second element (lets call it q_2) and so on. Every element is a symbolic element depending on another independent element (in my case that's the time t).

The overall idea is to create a growing second order ODE that I want to solve and plot in every loop.

The first step I already implemented, is the for-loop but I struggle with creating a new symbolic variable inside the loop. My first idea was to create the variable by name so I can use the iteration index i of the loop and create a new unique string every loop, but I don't know how to accomplish this with Maxima.

Comment: In Matlab this is done with the sym-command like: a = sym('a1').

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways.

- use subscripted symbolic variables, e.g., `u[1], u[2], u[3], ...`.
- use gensyms (generated symbol names which are guaranteed to be different from any other existing symbol. E.g. `gensym()` returns something like `g4282`, then next time `gensym()` returns `g4283`, etc.
- construct a symbol via `concat`, e.g. `concat('foo, 3)` returns `foo3`. THIS IS THE SOLUTION OF LAST RESORT. TRY ANYTHING ELSE BEFORE RESORTING TO CONCAT. It is too easy to make a mess that way.

If you show the code you have so far, maybe I can give more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the accepted answer, here is an example (using the `concat` method) of a `for` loop creating a matrix `M` with "indexed" symbols `e_ij` as elements:

```
M: zeromatrix(6,6)$
for r: 1 thru 6 do (
    for c: 1 thru 6 do (
        M[r][c]: concat('e_,r,c)
        )
    )$
```